# Is Conjure Dremora Lord under Necromancy or Atromancy?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

My conjured dremora seem quite weak and die very easily from hits my storm atronachs easily survive. Furthermore, I can't seem to be able to conjure a 'potent' dremora lord. I only got the Atromancy perks. So I'm wondering, is the conjure dremora lord spell under necromancy or atromancy?

Answer (score 2):

The Wiki suggests that there is no perk to raise the effectiveness of [Conjure Dremora Lord](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Conjure_Dremora_Lord)

> Although you must have a fairly high level of Conjuration Skill to summon a Dremora Lord, no Perks are required to summon one, or raise its strength.
>
> The dremora lord is not affected by Elemental potency, as it is not an atronach. It is, however, affected by twin souls, despite the description saying that you can have two summoned atronarchs or zombies.